# Is it possible to use HERE Map with firebase firestore database?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, here-api

I need to build an web app connected with the mobile app. i have to locate the location of the mobile on my web app. is it possible to get the lat and lng of all devices if i use the firestore for the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you can store data in firestore and can get it to show on your web app.